# Keyboard shortcut for 'Clear filters' in excel in office 365 for mac

Tags: keyboard, office-365

How do you 'clear filters' in excel in office 365 for mac using the keyboard?

On PC I can do alt+d,f,s

or using the mouse I can go to Data > Filter > Clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Remove / Enable a Filter in the Microsoft Excel for Mac through shortcut, do the following:

1. Select either 1 Cell OR the Entire Row with / to be filter
2. Press the combo → <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

Confirmed to be working with Excel ver 16.73 on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

Answer (score -3):

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: that shortcut doesn't work on a mac (even if you use Option instead of Alt of course - the shortcut is not supported on Mac OS).